# Android Studio Enable Inject Language/Reference

Tags: android, android-studio

I accidentally disabled the 'Inject Language/Reference' of the `android:title` in `Preference`. After that, now I won't able to go to the reference of the string.

```
<Preference
            android:title="@string/refreshing" <-- disabled
            android:key="refreshing" <-- enabled
/>
```

[image]

I'm using Android Studio, any ideas to enable it again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem. In Android Studio select the text and then press <kbd>Mac</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Then type un-inject Language/Reference. Hope that helps.

Comment: You save me from this annoying thing. CTRL+SHIFT+A on Windows

Comment: @NaviRamyle on Linux ?